# I can't make REST call to the localhost server for RESTful webservices

Tags: json, ajax, rest

```
$.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/speed-search-api/keys/getAll",
                crossDomain : true,
                dataType : "jsonp",
                type : "GET",
                success: function(data){
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data[0].keyName;
                }
            });
```

When i am trying to make a call to localhost which has RESTful services, it doesn't display anything? I am wondering why? POSTMAN i can see the data.

Comment: Is this a cross domain request?

Comment: Which domain served this JavaScript? Is it coming from localhost?